# What are the main components to a javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript

```
I edited this post to present it with better clarity of what I'm actually asking.
```

My confusion was and to some extent still is not being clear on the components that make up a slideshow in javascript. 
    To the best of my understanding the slideshow has these basic components that makes it work: 1) The array, 2) the preload declaration, 3) the counter, which is the for loop, and 4) the next image function. And of course the onclick button to execute the event. The onclick button calls the next image function. I redid the code. Although, it is not quite working I have no errors and no warnings. Everything looks similar to the tutorials I've been looking at. Any suggestions before I submit my homework. Thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>slideshow</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 //create array of image objects

 var myPic=new Array("photos/picture0.jpg",
                "photos/picture1.jpg",
                "photos/picture2.jpg",
                "photos/picture3.jpg",
                "photos/picture4.jpg")
 var num=0; //I believe this is my index
 //I don't understand why I'm creating a new array here.
 //I saw it in two different tutorials
 var preLoad=new Array(5)
 //Here I'm initializing the counter and preloading the images.
 for(i=0;i<myPic.length;i++)
 {
preLoad[i]=new Image()//Don't understand this part yet or the next line.
                    //I saw it in a tutorial

preLoad[i].src=myPic[i]
 }
 //this is to load the next image, reset the counter and end the loop.
 function nextImg()
 {
if(num<preLoad.length-1){
num=num+1;
document.getElementById("myImg").src=preLoad[num].src
}
else{   
num=0
document.getElementById("myImg").src=preLoad[num].src
}
 }
 </script>
 <!--So far no errors, no warnings.-->
 </head>
 <body>
 <img id="myImg" src="photos/picture0.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="firt picture"   border="3"/>
 <input type="button" value="show next picture" onclick="nextImg)" />
 </body>
 `enter code here`</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's this...?

```
<form name="show" align: center; />
```

that looks like style information but it's sitting there naked, and you don't need style on a form anyway, since it's not a displayed thing.

also, you have a bunch of mistakes here, but your biggest one is that you're not understanding how arrays work. Your code isn't doing what you *think it's doing.  you're incrementing myPic which isn't an integer, it's an array. What you need to be incrementing is an index IN the array...

```
myPic = new Array('a','b','c');
myIndex = 0;

var currentLetter = myPic[ index ] ;//currentLetter is now 'a'
index++;
currentLetter = myPic[ index ]; // currentLetter is now 'b'
```

I'm not sure what you mean by i==[0]... I suspect you mean i == 0? or you're again confusing how looping through arrays works.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at many examples and I thought I understood. I could have followed the examples, but my assignment is specific and I have to use certain things. I'm confused about the index, how to name it as a variable. I know it is the []. If I could just understand more about things like the "i" I used. I used it because I saw it used in someone else's code. Am I suppose to declare it and a index as a variable?

Comment: ha.. I remember i being SO confusing... where does it come from?!  As it turns out, i is an arbitrary variable.  It could be absolutely anything, it doesn't matter at all (j or k or abracadabra). You use it simply to keep track of some value.  So, you declare it to be 0 and then increment it as you go through your list, inserting it into the brackets... that's how you look at a field in an array myArray[ 7 ] is the 8th element of myArray.  If you say for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) and then use myArray[ i ] you will go through every element one at a time, from 0 to 7 (because the length is 8).

Comment: Great. It's good to get some clarification on things. I kept seeing that i everywhere and I wondered what it referenced. I understand about index starting at 0. I think I understand the for loop format, we just covered that last week in another assignment that I got a hundred percent on. Now I got to get the preloading  function solved. Isn't that actually the first function and the for loop is inside it.

Comment: I forgot to say that I got the page to open in the browser. I still can't figure out why it wasn't opening. I think I left a tag open because all my code in the body was pink.